# Module not found error when deploying node.js app to render.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to deploy my ecommerce backend app to render.com but it logs this error message:

```
Oct 19 12:56:30 PM  ==> Starting service with 'npm start'
Oct 19 12:56:33 PM  
Oct 19 12:56:33 PM  > api@1.0.0 start /opt/render/project/src
Oct 19 12:56:33 PM  > node ./server.js
Oct 19 12:56:33 PM  
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM                                ^
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/Middleware/AuthMiddleware.js' imported from /opt/render/project/src/Routes/ProductRoutes.js
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM      at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:276:11)
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM      at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:699:10)
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM      at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:810:11)
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM      at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:88:40)
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM      at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:241:28)
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM      at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:56:40)
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM      at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:55:36) {
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM    code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  }
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  npm ERR! errno 1
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  npm ERR! api@1.0.0 start: `node ./server.js`
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  npm ERR! Exit status 1
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  npm ERR!
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  npm ERR! Failed at the api@1.0.0 start script.
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Oct 19 12:56:34 PM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2022-10-19T11_56_34_819Z-debug.log
Oct 19 12:58:05 PM  ==> Starting service with 'npm start'
Oct 19 12:58:08 PM  
Oct 19 12:58:08 PM  > api@1.0.0 start /opt/render/project/src
Oct 19 12:58:08 PM  > node ./server.js
Oct 19 12:58:08 PM  
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM                                ^
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/Middleware/AuthMiddleware.js' imported from /opt/render/project/src/Routes/ProductRoutes.js
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM      at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:276:11)
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM      at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:699:10)
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM      at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:810:11)
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM      at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:88:40)
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM      at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:241:28)
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM      at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:56:40)
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM      at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:55:36) {
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM    code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  }
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  npm ERR! errno 1
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  npm ERR! api@1.0.0 start: `node ./server.js`
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  npm ERR! Exit status 1
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  npm ERR!
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  npm ERR! Failed at the api@1.0.0 start script.
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Oct 19 12:58:09 PM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2022-10-19T11_58_09_816Z-debug.log
```

It says "cannot find module AuthMiddleware.js" but I have checked and I imported it already. Here is a sample of my package.json, and productRoute.

`Product route`

```
import express from "express";
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import { admin, protect } from "../Middleware/AuthMiddleware.js";
import Product from "../Models/ProductModel.js";
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./server.js",
    "frontend": "cd frontend && npm start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run frontend\" \"npm run server\"",
    "server": "node ./server.js",
```

What could be the issue?
I don't know what to do because I specified in my package.json that the type is "module" and the solutions on here are mostly telling me to do that. So please is there anything wrong, do you need any additional information from me?

Comment: Can you share the structure of your project? Do you have an `src` directory?